# CSS Transitions don't survive React Component changing inner DOM structure

Tags: css, dom, reactjs, css-transitions, react-dom

[I have illustrated the problem in this CodePen](https://codepen.io/muehl/pen/xOGQpN/)

```
const Component = ({ structure }) => {
  switch (structure) {
    case 'nested': 
      return (
        <div>
          <AnimatedComponent />
      </div>
     );
    case 'flat': 
      return 
        <AnimatedComponent />
      ;
  }
};
```

There's some logic in `AnimatedComponent` that changes the styling of the Component in an animated fashion, e.g. change the background color from black to red over a duration of 1 second. The animation is started by changing a color class on `AnimatedComponent`. There is CSS to handle the animation given the changed class.

When changing the DOM structure from nested to flat, the HTML element is destroyed and recreated, the transition starting state is lost (aka the browser doesn't know which class was set before because the element was newly created).

What I want React to do is to change the DOM structure with moving elements in new positions, not destroying and recreating them.

Is this possible?

I tried to use the `key` props on `<AnimatedComponent />`, but it only fixes the flash of DOM change. Animation is skipped. See [Codepen](http://codepen.io/muehl/pen/JKdwbX). Thanks [Thomas Rooney](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1270144/thomasrooney) for this suggestion.

Can I tell React to apply the class changes just one tick after the position of the DOM element was changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I tell React to apply the class changes just one tick after the position of the DOM element was changed?

Yes, this is precisely what the `setTimeout` function is for. Copying your second example, where you fixed the flickering, wrapping your color action dispatch with `setTimeout` (with no time value, which defaults to 0), seems to fix your issue.

```
onColorClick: () => {
  setTimeout(() => { 
    dispatch({type: 'TOGGLE_COLOR'})
  })
},
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/alex-wilmer/pen/ezNbPp?editors=1010)

Update: I've noticed it's a bit more reliable to add some time before the color change (second argument in `setTimeout`, `(fn, ms)`. I believe this is because `setState` is also happening asynchronously.

```
onColorClick: () => {
  setTimeout(() => { 
    dispatch({type: 'TOGGLE_COLOR'})
  }, 100) <-- play around with this value
},
```

Comment: This is working as intended! There's only a bug but it doesn't matter to my issue at hand. When you're in the nested state and click the `change both` button 2 times in a row, there's a color flash on box 2.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a bug so much as it is the way CSS3 animations work--they cannot be interrupted. If you're looking for something more fluid take a look at https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion

Comment: I've just tired it. Well, we are just delaying the state/prop changes. I don't think this can replace **transition...